# Unable to login to Ubuntu with my user password that was created during installation

Tags: ubuntu, password-recovery

After the installation of Ubuntu 15.04 on my second laptop using same DVD,
I'm unable to login with my password that was created during installation.

Comment: forgot password ? password typo ? keyboard in a different LANG setting ?

Answer (score 7):

Check to make sure that you have typed your login password correctly and that you are using the correct keyboard input language setting when you are typing the password.

If that doesn't work and you have forgotten your user password, then you need to reset your lost administrative password.

---

#### Reset lost administrative password

1. Immediately after the motherboard / computer manufacturer logo splash screen appears when the computer is booting, with BIOS, quickly press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, which will bring up a GNU GRUB menu screen. With UEFI press (perhaps several times) the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to get to the GNU GRUB menu screen. Sometimes the manufacturer's splash screen is a part of the Windows bootloader, so when you power up the machine it goes straight to the GNU GRUB menu screen, and then pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> is unnecessary.

   The timing when to press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> key can be tricky, so sometimes if you miss it you need to try it again. If that doesn't work try the answers to [I can't get the GRUB menu to show up during boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/87409/).

   You will see a GNU GRUB menu screen that looks like this. Select **Advanced options for Ubuntu** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

2. A new purple screen will appear showing a list of kernels, which includes options of booting the kernels normally or in recovery mode.

[image]

```
Press the down arrow key until you select the **2nd entry from the top** (the one with the **recovery mode in the description**) and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice.
```

3. Now you should see this recovery menu. From the Recovery Menu screen, use the arrow keys scroll down to ***root**  Drop to root shell prompt* and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   [image]
4. You'll see a root prompt, something like this: `root@ubuntu:~#`. Remount it with write permissions:

   ```
    mount -rw -o remount /
   ```
5. To reset the password, type `passwd username` where you replace `username` with the username you use to login with.
6. You'll be prompted to type a new password. When you type the password you will get no visual response acknowledging your typing to prevent other people from seeing your password as you type it. Type your new password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
7. You'll be prompted to type your new password again as a check to make sure that you have typed it correctly. Type your new password again and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
8. You will see a message that says: `passwd: password updated successfully` showing that your password has been successfully reset. If Ubuntu is installed on an SSD, type `sync` to force changed blocks to disk and update the super block.
9. Type `exit` to return to the recovery menu.
10. From the Recovery Menu select `resume Resume normal boot` to resume booting normally.

Comment: The "sync" maneuver, multiple times, is a good idea regardless of drive type. - If you cannot get to that menu, appending init=/bin/sh to the kernel command line will also drop you to a root shell.